# Can UIScrollView zoomToRect?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uikit

Is there a way to determine whether a UIScrollView can `zoomToRect:` within `maximumZoomScale` and `minimumZoomScale`? So return NO if the required `zoomScale` would be too small?

Comment: check this :http://stackoverflow.com/a/2125472/845115

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this sort of thing might work? (idea slightly stolen from https://stackoverflow.com/a/2125472/845115)

```
- (BOOL)scrollView:(UIScrollView*)scrollView canZoomToRect:(CGRect)zoomToRect {
    CGPoint contentOffsetBefore = scrollView.contentOffset;
    CGFloat zoomBefore = scrollView.zoomScale;
    [scrollView zoomToRect:zoomToRect animated:NO];
    CGFloat zoomAfter = scrollView.zoomScale;

    [scrollView setZoomScale:zoomBefore animated:NO];
    [scrollView setContentOffset:contentOffsetBefore animated:NO];

    return (zoomBefore == zoomAfter);
}
```